# Classes aninhadas em Java são como closures?

Tags: java

Ouvi dizer que classes aninhadas possuem um comportamento semelhante a closures.Isto está correto?

Comment: Pode-se dizer que sim em algumas situações, mas não exatamente, elas são usadas para substituir *closures*. É um mecanismo mais exposto e um pouco mais flexível. Ele pode ser usado para outras coisas. Como agora Java possui *closure* ele tenderá ser menos usado em APIs novas (pelo menos para isso). Mas ainda tem utilidade. Se der eu tento uma resposta depois.

Comment: @bigown Seria muito bom, obrigado!

Comment: Tem um exemplo?